# Bug Tag Removal

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

[bug](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) as a tag makes no sense as we don't allow those questions.

Comment: What about questions for *workarounds* around particular bugs?  (Just asking.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[bug](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) has been updated to ask users to stop and let them know that bugs are off-topic. We could've burninated and blocked the tag but I think then we'd get the same tech support questions just without the bug tag. [Within the complete Bug tag description](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info) are links to some common manufacturer websites. Feel free to add additional ones or makes changes to the links.

I also went through and either hammered or removed the bug tag from every question it was on.